# Angularjs - hide div with "if" and "else"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would only like to show a div when user is logged in and on their profile but disabled when logged off and on another users profile.

I attempted to do this below but was unsuccessful. I would like to know what is the best possible way of going about this?

`Service.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.authentication.services')
    .factory('Authentication', Authentication);

  Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http'];

  function Authentication($cookies, $http) {

    var Authentication = {
      getAuthenticatedAccount: getAuthenticatedAccount,
      isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated
    };

    return Authentication;

    function getAuthenticatedAccount() {
        if(!$cookies.authenticatedAccount) {
            return;
        }
        return JSON.parse($cookies.authenticatedAccount);
    }
    function isAuthenticated() {
        return !!$cookies.authenticatedAccount;
    }  
})();
```

`Controller.js`

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.profiles.controllers')
    .controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

ProfileController.$inject = ['$location', '$routeParams', 'Posts', 'Profile', 'Snackbar'];

function ProfileController($location, $routeParams, Posts, Profile, Authentication, Snackbar) {
    var vm = this;

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var authenticatedAccount = Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount();
        var username = $routeParams.username.substr(1);

         // This will show Cog settings button 
        // when user is logged in and on their profile, 
       // but hidden when logged off and also when on 
       // another users profile

        if (!authenticatedAccount) {
            vm.profileCog = false;
            // console.log('User not logged in');
        }
        else {
            if(authenticatedAccount.username !== username) {
                vm.profileCog = false;
                // console.log('Not logged in user');
            }
            else {
                vm.profileCog = true;
               //console.log('logged in user');
            }
    }
}
 })();
```

`profile.html`

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCogController">
    <div ng-show="!profileCog"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is profileCog() called? It's private within ProfileController.

Comment: @WayneEllery that was a no brainer. I fixed that. My attempt was making it a boolean and it would return true only if the user was on his/her profile. I would just like to know how to properly achieve this.

Comment: You are on the right track. Use `ng-show` to show hide. To do if use `ng-show="profileCog"`. To do else use `ng-hide="profileCog"` or `ng-show="!profileCog"`

Comment: is `getAuthenticatedAccount` asynchronous?

Comment: @WayneEllery I did what you said. Unfortunately It shows the div on the other profiles  as well as the logged in user. if I change ng-show to ng-show="profileCog" it makes the div disappear on all the pages.

Comment: @scniro yes it is asynchronous

Comment: how will you ever get the real value for this if you are not evaluating it in the callback of `getAuthenticatedAccount`? You likely need to move that logic into a `then()`

Comment: I see you've taken a look at John Papa's style guide ;D

Comment: "if I change ng-show to ng-show="profileCog" it makes the div disappear on all the pages". That's because `vm.profileCog` is always being evaluated to false. This can only mean that `!authenticatedAccount` is always true, and `authenticatedAccount.username !== username` is always true.

Comment: @JoshBeam actually no, I never heard of John Papa's style guide haha. I learned most everything through Thinkster.io...I try not to ask silly questions on here to take up peoples time for nothing. I hope this was not one of them:P

Comment: @AustinPerez, not a silly question! Lol I suggest reading it, you're following all the recommended patterns. I guess Thinkster.io bases their curriculum off of his style guide.

Comment: @JoshBeam Well that is good to hear haha. Thanks yea I will check it out and read up on it. Thanks for sharing it

Comment: @AustinPerez have you made any forward progress on this?

Comment: @scniro I am still trying to work it out. I have been attempting yours and Josh Beam's answers. I keep getting a console error that reads: "Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount(...).then is not a function"

Comment: it must not be asynchronous then, in fact, I don't see usage of `$http` anywhere in that factory of yours. Can you `console.log` out and share the result of `authenticatedAccount` right after your `Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount()` call?

Comment: @scniro I edited my post again to show what I have changed. I am able to show on the console whether it is the users profile, not their profile, and if user is logged out. For whatever reason, I still cannot make ng-show work with the "vm.profileCog = true;". Does it now have something to do with my scope objects?

Comment: @scniro Just solved the my question. Thank you for your help. If you could, could you accept it and vote it up! lol

Comment: ahhhh `vm.` I see, so simple I think we all overlooked it. Well, you'll need to accept your own answer I am unable to do that for you :)

Comment: @scniro I know, such a small thing. Oh that's true, you can't accept...duh. But you can upvote! Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

`controller.js`

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('resonanceinn.profiles.controllers')
    .controller('ProfileCogController', ProfileCogController);

ProfileCogController.$inject = ['Authentication', '$routeParams', 'Profile'];

function ProfileCogController(Authentication, $routeParams, Profile) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.profileCog = false;

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var authenticatedAccount = Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount();
        var username = $routeParams.username.substr(1);

        if (!authenticatedAccount) {
            vm.profileCog = false;
            // console.log('User not logged in');
        }
        else {
            if(authenticatedAccount.username !== username) {
                vm.profileCog = false;
                // console.log('Not logged in user');
            } else {
                vm.profileCog = true;
                // console.log('logged in user');
            }
        }
    }
}
})();
```

`profile.html`

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCogController">
    <div ng-show="vm.profileCog"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment that `getAuthenticatedAccount` is always asynchronous:

This means you'll need to either A) explicitly watch it, or B) evaluate it once it completes. Something like this:

```
function activate() {
  Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount().then(function(account) {
    var username = $routeParams.username.substr(1);

    if(!account || account.username !== username) {
      vm.profileCog = false;
    }
  });

// rest of code omitted
```

You'll need to make sure that `Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount` returns a promise for this to work (by default, async calls using AngularJS internal libraries should always return a promise, aka, something that is `then`able).

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify the controller and app name in your html file:

1) specify the controller and app name in any parent tag of current div tag if any

2) otherwise, specify the same with in the same div tag
Like:

```js
angular.module('showApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isvisible=false;
  $scope.showDiv=function()
  {
    if(!$scope.isvisible)
      $scope.isvisible=true
      else
        $scope.isvisible=false
  }
        
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"  >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title> 

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="showApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  Show me: <input type="checkbox" ng-click="showDiv()" ><br/>

  <div  ng-show="isvisible">I show up when your checkbox is checked.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Comment: This does not help. My controller is defined in my routes.js. My app is defined in my index.html where ng-view shows templates loaded.