# Why is my tag still showing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is what's inside my controller what's wrong with the way I pass the values?  I also tried putting it inside a function still didn't fixed it.  I removed some parts of the code since I'm just pointing out on how to show or hide the div using angularjs `ng-show`.  I followed the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174018/angularjs-hide-div-with-if-and-else)

```
var atag = this;
    atag.vaAnchor = false;
    atag.nseAnchor = false;
//showAnchor();
  // function showAnchor(){
var encodedString = 'action=' +
                    encodeURIComponent("checkLogin") +
                    '&user=' +
                    encodeURIComponent(dataForm.datausername) +
                    '&pw=' +
                    encodeURIComponent(dataForm.datapassword);
            $scope.errorMsg = ""; //reset the error message
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                if ( data[0]["Data"] != undefined) {
                    $scope.errorMsg = "Incorrect Username/Password";
                    $("#mypass").focus();
                } 
                else if ( data[0]["Data"] === undefined)  {

                    Apprsal.setUsertype(data[0]["Type"]);

                    if(Apprsal.userSelectedData().usertype === "")
                    {
                        atag.vaAnchor = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        atag.nseAnchor=true;
                    }
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                      disableBack: true
                    });
                    $state.go('app.main');
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.errorMsg = 'Unable to submit form' + status;
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            })
        }

//}
```

And this is whats inside my html:

```
 <li>
             <a href="#/app/va-contact" ng-show="atag.vaAnchor">
               <i class="icon ion-ios-people"></i>
                 <span>Contacts</span>
             </a>
        </li>

     <!-- For NSE only -->
    <li>
         <a href="#" id="lnkCorp" ng-show="atag.nseAnchor">
              <i class="icon ion-ios-people"></i>
                 <span>Contacts</span>
         </a>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#" id="lnkNetwork" ng-show="atag.nseAnchor">
             <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i>
                 <span>Planner</span>
         </a>
     </li>      
        <li>
               <a href="#" id="lnkNetworkVA" ng-show="atag.vaAnchor">
                 <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i>
                       <span>Planner</span>
                </a>
          </li>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: hmm, i know what the problem is now, i'll just edit the question first

Comment: How are you making the AJAX request from your controller? If you are not using angular's $http service, angular may not be triggering any updates when the .success() is called.

Answer (score 1):

Please change 
`ng-show="atag.nseAnchor"`
to
`ng-show="nseAnchor"`

If i understand correctly, atag is your $scope. So no need inside html.

Comment: well I'm just new to angularjs actually.. i tried what you suggested didn't work, but thanks for your reply. atag isn't a $scope but a local variable inside a controller